# iPhone: first song not pause before start next song

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, audio-streaming

In My app Song play through buffering,

I have two music player in my app,

But it plays both  musicplayer songs together. It does not pause the first song even when I try to pause.

i refer this tutorial:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

for that i try to call

[streamer pause];

```
- (void)pause
```

{

```
 @synchronized(self)

{

    if (state == AS_PLAYING)

    {
        err = AudioQueuePause(audioQueue);

        if (err)

        {

            [self failWithErrorCode:AS_AUDIO_QUEUE_PAUSE_FAILED];
            return;

        }
        self.state = AS_PAUSED;
    }
    else if (state == AS_PAUSED)
    {
        err = AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);
        if (err)
        {
            [self failWithErrorCode:AS_AUDIO_QUEUE_START_FAILED];
            return;
        }
        self.state = AS_PLAYING;
    }
}
```

}

streamer calls the pause method of buffering.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (audioPlayer.playing==YES) {
        [audioPlayer pause];
  }
```

try this.